# Spring : registering bean by private method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am configuring spring security,below is my code-

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
}

@Bean(name="encoder")
public BCryptPasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
...
}
```

As soon as I applied @Autowire on-

```
@Override
@Autowire
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    }
```

This throws exception no bean of type 'HttpSecurity' in container,this is expected.

But when I applied `@Autowire` on-

```
@Override
@Autowire
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
    }
```

There is no exception?**how this `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` bean is in bean factory?**

when I changed my bean registration with private method like this-

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
}

@Bean(name="encoder")
private BCryptPasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

**This is throwing exception,method cant be private.Why so?**

Comment: You have two questions. The latter should be self-explanatory. For the first, are you using Boot?

Comment: @chrylis this is spring mvc project,Iam not using spring boot here.

Answer (score 9):

From the Spring Documentation

> Typically, @Bean methods are declared within @Configuration classes. In this case, bean methods may reference other @Bean methods in the same class by calling them directly. This ensures that references between beans are strongly typed and navigable. Such so-called 'inter-bean references' are guaranteed to respect scoping and AOP semantics, just like getBean() lookups would. These are the semantics known from the original 'Spring JavaConfig' project which require CGLIB subclassing of each such configuration class at runtime. As a consequence, @Configuration classes and their factory methods must not be marked as final or private in this mode

[Ref link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)